# Blank node skolemization in SPARQL without iteration

Tags: sparql, blank-nodes

Is it possible to implement [blank node skolemization](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#section-skolemization) in SPARQL without iteration? It seems to me that iteration is required to skolemize chains of blank nodes, such as:

```
@prefix : <http://example.com/> .

[ a :A ;
  :p1 [
    a :B
  ]
] .
```

A SPARQL Update operation for skolemization can start from the blank nodes that appear as subjects only in triples without blank node objects:

```
DELETE {
  ?b1 ?outP ?outO .
  ?inS ?inP ?b1 .
}
INSERT {
  ?iri ?outP ?outO .
  ?inS ?inP ?iri .
}
WHERE {
  {
    SELECT ?b1 (uuid() AS ?iri)
    WHERE {
      {
        SELECT DISTINCT ?b1
        WHERE {
          ?b1 ?p1 [] .
          FILTER isBlank(?b1)
          FILTER NOT EXISTS {
            ?b1 ?p2 ?b2 .
            FILTER isBlank(?b2)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ?b1 ?outP ?outO .
  OPTIONAL {
    ?inS ?inP ?b1 .
  }
}
```

This operation can be repeated until no blank nodes are found in the data:

```
ASK {
  ?bnode ?p [] .
  FILTER isBlank(?bnode)
}
```

Is it possible to avoid the iteration and implement the blank node skolemization in a single SPARQL Update operation?

(Also, this approach assumes there are no "orphan" blank nodes (i.e. blank nodes that appear only as objects).)

Answer (score 2):

I found a two-step solution skolemising subjects and objects separately and storing the blank node aliases (links between blank nodes and IRIs via `owl:sameAs`) as intermediate data:

```
PREFIX :    <http://example.com/>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

####################
# Rewrite subjects #
####################

DELETE {
  ?bnode ?p ?o .
}
INSERT {
  ?iri ?p ?o .
  GRAPH :aliases {
    ?bnode owl:sameAs ?iri .
  }
}
WHERE {
  {
    SELECT ?bnode (uuid() AS ?iri)
    WHERE {
      {
        SELECT DISTINCT ?bnode
        WHERE {
          ?bnode ?p [] .
          FILTER isBlank(?bnode)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ?bnode ?p ?o .
}
;

###################
# Rewrite objects #
###################

DELETE {
  ?s ?p ?bnode .
}
INSERT {
  ?s ?p ?iri .
}
WHERE {
  {
    SELECT ?bnode ?iri
    WHERE {
      {
        SELECT DISTINCT ?bnode
        WHERE {
          [] ?p ?bnode .
          FILTER isBlank(?bnode)
        }
      }
      OPTIONAL {
        GRAPH :aliases {
          ?bnode owl:sameAs ?_iri .
        }
      }
      BIND (coalesce(?_iri, uuid()) AS ?iri)
    }
  }
  ?s ?p ?bnode .
}
;

############################
# Clear blank node aliases #
############################

CLEAR GRAPH :aliases
```